# calling python function with arguments using tcl script

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, tcl

I have a python script (sample.py) that has a function with 3 arguments. where 1st two arguments are in hex and 3rd is the string.

```
def sampleFun(gen_lane,sw_state,test_name):`
    
    ### code segment 

    output = "some string"
    return output
```

I have to use tcl script to call this function sampleFun present in sample.py.

How to do that?
I have tried this tcl command :

```
proc call_python { } {
    set gen_lane 0x10500000
    set sw_state 0x0000000B
    set test_case "linkup"
    set result [exec python -c "import sample; print sample.sampleFun($gen_lane,$sw_state,$test_case)"]
    puts $result

}
```

But I am getting the error that the name "linkup" is not defined.

So, how to pass a string argument to the python function from tcl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote it for Python.

For an almost-arbitrary value like that, you'd try this:

```
set result [exec python -c "import sample; print sample.print_file($gen_lane,$sw_state,r'''$test_case''')"]
```

This uses the fact that `'''`-quoted strings in Python can contain newlines and single `'` characters, and `r` strings can contain backslashes. The cases remaining that could possibly cause problems are rare.

You are aware that your example Python code said `sampleFun` but your test code said `sample.print_file`? I assume you can fix that up…

Comment: Truly general value passing requires a totally different approach, as an arbitrary Tcl string might include binary data, including NULs. It's not a common problem… but the general case is where you have to deal with those awkward edge cases as well. At that point, you're going to be into doing transfer of data via temporary files, sockets or pipes… and that's a _lot_ more work!

Comment: Hi Donal, 
If my python script sample.py is in some other directory then how to import it?
Because above tcl proc works only when my both tcl script and python script are in same folder.

Comment: I don't know. I always run all my Python code installed inside a virtualenv so the question doesn't come up for me. I'm sure there'll be an answered question on Stack Overflow that describes what environment variable(s) to set...